# Determine the hyper-parameters of an Approximate Bayesian computation

Tags: python, performance, beginner, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel

I created my own [Approximate Bayesian computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation) algorithm in Python 3 and I try to find the best hyper-parameters for it but it is really slow. *This question is not about the math involved in it. For that, you can read [my other question on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419831/how-to-use-approximate-bayesian-computation-to-estimate-the-parameters-of-a-func).*

The objective of the ABC algorithm is to find the best distribution for the parameters of a model by using a Bayesian approach. To do that, I create a dataset with the *real* parameters of my model and I try to find all the values of \$a\$ and \$b\$ that produce the same outcome. Then, I use those new values of \$a\$ and \$b\$ to create my posterior distribution.

The purpose of my piece of code is to find the hyper-parameters \$k\$ and \$n\$ who give me the best compromise between precision and time of execution. The \$k\$ parameter corresponds to the size of the dataset I generate at each step and the \$n\$ parameter corresponds to the number of points I generate from my prior distribution.

For those two hyper-parameters, the higher the better but I want to check if increasing one of them has a big enough impact on the standard deviation of the parameter of my model.

So, here is my question: what can I do to improve the speed of my algorithm?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.stats import uniform
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Because I want to find the best hyper-parameters for my model,
# I will create a dataset with fixed parameters
real_a = 0.9
real_b = -0.02

# Make m steps for each set of hyper-parameters
m = 100

# Return the probability that a Bernoulli trial will success
def gen_model(a, b, odd):
    prob = a / odd + b
    prob = 0.0 if prob < 0.0 else prob
    prob = 1.0 if prob > 1.0 else prob
    return prob

def bernoulli_trial(p):
    return np.random.rand() <= p

# Return the outcome of a Bernoulli trial with the fixed parameters
def real_exp(odd):
    return bernoulli_trial(gen_model(real_a, real_b, odd))

# k is one of my hyper-parameters. It represents the number of rows of my dataset
for k in range(5,11):
    # n = 10 ** p is the second hyper-parameter. It represents the number of tuples (a,b) I generate for each run
    for p in range(5,8):
        n = 10 ** p
        # Three results for each hyper-parameters tuple
        for l in range(3):
            # The first time, I pick the parameters from a normal distribution
            first = True

            posterior = None

            last_a_mean = 1.0
            last_a_std = 0.0

            last_b_mean = 0.0
            last_b_std = 0.0

            for run in range(m):
                selected_parameters = [[], []]

                # Accept the parameters only if at least 100 are non-rejected
                while(len(selected_parameters[0]) < 100):
                    current_loop_odd = []
                    current_loop_result = []

                    for idx in range(k): # Creation of my dataset
                        current_loop_odd.append(1 / uniform.rvs(0.01, 0.99))
                        current_loop_result.append(real_exp(current_loop_odd[idx]))

                    for loop in range(n):
                        add_selected_parameters = True

                        if first: # My prior is a and b are independent and follow a normal distribution (mean of 1 for a and mean of 0 for b)
                            a = norm.rvs(1.0,0.1)
                            b = norm.rvs(0.0,0.1)
                        else: # For the next steps, I use datapoints generated from my posterior distribution
                            a = points[0][loop]
                            b = points[1][loop]

                        for idx in range(k): 
                            if bernoulli_trial(gen_model(a, b, current_loop_odd[idx])) != current_loop_result[idx]:
                                add_selected_parameters = False # The tuple is rejected because it doesn't correspond to my dataset

                        if add_selected_parameters:                
                            selected_parameters[0].append(a)
                            selected_parameters[1].append(b)

                posterior = gaussian_kde(selected_parameters) # I generate a new posterior distribution from my non-rejected tuples
                points = posterior.resample(n) # And I create new datapoints for the next step
                first = False

                last_a_mean = np.mean(selected_parameters[0])
                last_a_std = np.std(selected_parameters[0])

                last_b_mean = np.mean(selected_parameters[1])
                last_b_std = np.std(selected_parameters[1])

            # Print the result
            print(str(k) + " - " + str(n) + " : (" + str(l) + ") -> " + str(last_a_mean) + " , " + str(last_a_std) + " / " + str(last_a_mean) + " , " + str(last_a_std))
```

Comment: Explain at the top, specific requests at the top, code at the bottom.

Comment: A style note: Comments in code are generally incomplete - you could stick a noun in front of them, and it would work: `# make m steps for each set of hyper-parameters` however this suggestion does not qualify for an answer

Comment: @FreezePhoenix I put the code at the end of the question.

Comment: A general code-review.se rule: When someone suggests a change specific to the code, such as I did in my second comment, you don't edit your question. And when someone answers a question, you still don't edit it. This is to keep answers from having to change as comments are added to the post.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix I'm OK with what you say about changing the question after an answer but I didn't have any answer to my question.

Comment: You edited it after I suggested a change to your code. That is discouraged here.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix Okay, sorry, I didn't see that in the FAQ. What should I have done after reading your comment, so?

Comment: > "A style note" You should just note it, and if you write a second question with your improved code, or once you apply answers to your code, take into consideration the notes people have left.